# How to pass a variable to firebase serve --only functions to switch databases for testing?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm using `firebase serve --only functions` to emulate my cloud functions locally.

My cloud functions can connect to different firebase realtime databases. One is for production, and one is for testing. Right now, I am manually changing the databases for testing. This is bad practice because I could accidentally commit or deploy the functions with the incorrect database.

```
const mainDb = admin.database();
const testDb = admin.database(testApp);
var currentDb = mainDb;

// Used for testing locally
exports.switchTest = function() {
  currentDb = testDb;
};

// Uncomment this line to use test db
// exports.switchTest();
```

What's the best way to trigger the database switch without modifying files that I have to switch around? Can I pass in a variable like `firebase deploy --only functions --options=test` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, developers take advantage of the Firebase CLI to switch between projects for dev/stage/prod by using the `firebase use` command.  You can [set up aliases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#use_project_aliases) for each of your projects.

If you need to have everything within a single project for some reason (maybe not the best idea), you can use [environment variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) to configure the runtime properties of the emulator, and pull them out of `firebase.config()` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm trying to put everything in one project (which may not be the best idea, but it's our setup for now). One issue with using the environment variables is that they persist on the server as well. So we could set the variable to DEBUG=true, accidentally deploy that, and now the production cloud functions use DEBUG configurations. Is there a way to do this and avoid mistakes like this?

Comment: Env vars persist on the server after you perform a deploy.  That's by design.  You should avoid accidentally deploying bad configurations.  There's not much the tools can do to help you with that.  They just do whatever you tell them to do.